# How to disallow users with certain emails form posting?

Tags: advertising

On a Drupal 6 site, I struggle with some persistent spammer who uses different tricks to escape any regexp [spam](http://drupal.org/project/spam) filters. Whenever I delete him, he always uses certain email provider (e.g. somerandomname@blablamail.com) to register again.

So I am wondering how can I disalow blablamail.com altogether so that either users can not register with this email provider, or better, they can not post anything after registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add access rules from admin/user/rules.

The help for that administration page says:

> Set up username and e-mail address access rules for new and existing accounts (currently logged in accounts will not be logged out). If a username or e-mail address for an account matches any deny rule, but not an allow rule, then the account will not be allowed to be created or to log in. A host rule is effective for every page view, not just registrations.

Keep in mind the rules use the SQL regular expression, which means that:

- *%* matches any number of characters, even zero characters
- *_* matches exactly one character

Comment: Great! So I added a 'deny' email rule and entered  '%@blablamail.com'. Now no one can register with this email. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an access rule and deny creating an account or logging in with an account that matches certain criteria.

Go to *admin/user/rules* and add a new rule. In your case, the access type should be *deny*, rule type should be *e-mail*, and the mask can be '*%@blablamail.com*' for instance. You can test your new access rule by clicking on the *Check rules* tab afterwards.