# How to disallow some emails in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, emails, advertising

Some temporary emails are frequently used by human spammers and I want to disallow them either from registration or posting.

I know that there is a similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54928/how-to-disallow-users-with-certain-emails-form-posting) but that one is for D6 and did not work for me. I'd like to do that in D7. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [User Restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module. This module allows you to block both emails and usernames based on certain patterns.

For example, to block mails from spammers.com create a user restriction with:

- Access type: Denied
- Rule type: Email
- Mask: %spammers.com

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved with the ["user restrictions"](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module.

But the ["http:BL"](https://www.drupal.org/project/httpbl) module  could also be interesting for you!

you should check them out! ;)